# Unable to find DirectionsResult class in com.google.maps.model package

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was running few unit tests present in the link : https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java. I am unable to locate DirectionsResult class in the com.google.maps.model package package. I'm attaching the gradle dependencies snapshot and the code snippet that I used from one of the test case. Please let me know where am I going wrong ? Thanks !

[image]
[image]

The test case snippet was something like this :

```
package com.google.maps;

import com.google.maps.DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction;
import com.google.maps.errors.NotFoundException;
import com.google.maps.model.AddressType;
import com.google.maps.model.DirectionsResult;
import com.google.maps.model.GeocodedWaypointStatus;
import com.google.maps.model.TrafficModel;
import com.google.maps.model.TransitMode;
import com.google.maps.model.TransitRoutingPreference;
import com.google.maps.model.TravelMode;
import com.google.maps.model.Unit;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@Category(LargeTests.class)
public class DirectionsApiTest extends AuthenticatedTest {

private GeoApiContext context;

public DirectionsApiTest(GeoApiContext context) {
this.context = context
    .setQueryRateLimit(3)
    .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testGetDirections() throws Exception {
DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.getDirections(context, "Sydney, AU",
    "Melbourne, AU").await();
assertNotNull(result.routes);
assertNotNull(result.routes[0]);
assertThat(result.routes[0].overviewPolyline.decodePath().size(), not(0));
assertEquals("Sydney NSW, Australia", result.routes[0].legs[0].startAddress);
assertEquals("Melbourne VIC, Australia", result.routes[0].legs[0].endAddress);
}
}
```

Comment: Please share encountered error that appears in the console.

Comment: The error was class not found in the package. I've figured that after changing dependency from     compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.2' to compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.12'. I couldn't find any document that mentions that the class DirectionsResult is deprecated from package com.google.maps.model.DirectionsResult;

Answer (score 0):

The error was class not found in the package. I've figured that after changing dependency from compile 'com.google.maps:goo‌​gle-maps-services:0.1‌​.2' to compile 'com.google.maps:goo‌​gle-maps-services:0.1‌​.12'. I couldn't find any document that mentions that the class DirectionsResult is deprecated from package com.google.maps.mode‌​l.DirectionsResult;